# Programming in C, Switch Case problems

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
char ch;
//character = ch        
    printf("Please type a character [A-Z or a-z] ('x'to exit):");
    scanf("%c", &ch);   
        switch(ch) //switch statement
        {
        case 'a':
            printf("%c is a vowel.\n", ch);
                break; 
        case 'e':
            printf("%c is a vowel.\n", ch);
                break; 
        case 'i':
            printf("%c is a vowel.\n", ch);
                break; 
        case 'o':
            printf("%c is a vowel.\n", ch);
                break; 
        case 'u':
            printf("%c is a vowel.\n", ch);
                break; 
        case 'A':
            printf("%c is a vowel.\n", ch);
                break; 
        case 'E':
            printf("%c is a vowel.\n", ch);
                break; 
        case 'I':
            printf("%c is a vowel.\n", ch);
                break; 
        case 'O':
            printf("%c is a vowel.\n", ch);
                break; 
        case 'U': 
            printf("%c is a vowel.\n", ch);
                break; 
        default:
            if(ch != 'x'){
                printf("%c is a consonant.\n", ch); 
                    break; }
            else if(ch == 'x'){
                printf("%c is a consonant.\n", ch);
                    break; }
        }
```

I have been having much trouble with this code. I have it perfect however it needs to keep repeating until 'x' is entered. Tried a while loop, couldn't have any luck, just recently tried the if statement in the default, that doesnt work either. I'm so close if anyone could give me a little insight!

Comment: Show us your while loop implementation that's how you should do it! (unless you want to use functions)

Comment: A `while` loop, or perhaps a `do`-`while` loop, would be the right way to do this. You say you didn't have any luck with a while loop; we can't help without seeing your code *and* knowing how it failed. Can you update the question showing the version with the `while` loop? Also, you can combine multiple cases: `case 'a`: case 'e': case 'i': ...`

Comment: You can't use a `break` in a `switch` to break out of an enclosing loop.  And you should really check the return value from `scanf()` to be sure you got the character you expected.  I suspect that newline is a consonant in your code.  You could fix that by using `" %c"` (with a blank before the `%`) as the format string.

Comment: You may want to add a space `scanf(" %c", &ch);` to consume previous <enter>.

Answer (score 7):

1. You don't need to repeat yourself so much.  You can use multiple labels for a given case:

   ```
   case 'a':
   case 'e':
   case 'i':
   case 'o':
   case 'u':
   case 'A':
   case 'E':
   case 'I':
   case 'O':
   case 'U':
       printf("%c is a vowel.\n", ch);
       break;
   default:
       printf("%c is a consonant.\n", ch);
       break;
   ```
2. You do need a loop:

   ```
   do
   {
       printf(...)
       scanf(...)
       switch (...)
       {
          ...
       }
   } while (ch != 'x');
   ```
3. You might want to add an `isalpha` call in there before doing the `switch` at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(ch != 'x'){
  ...

  ...
}
```

or maybe you can do a function menu approach

```
void runMenu(){
     // do stuff
     runMenu();
}
```

I would look at @Carl Norum's answer for code optimization!